# SyntaxError: missing } after property list showing on jquery code execution

Tags: jquery, html

I have written a simple jquery code for shifting a div of buttons to right side. I have wrote a jquery code as this is the code here:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250">
<meta name="generator" content="PSPad editor, www.pspad.com">
<title></title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#leftscroll').click(function() {
      $('#buttonmove').animate({'marginLeft' : '+= 30px'
      )};                     

  )};         
)};
</script>
<style>
.button{
width:100px;
height:100px;}

div #buttonmove{
float:left;
margin: auto 0;
position:absolute;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <a id="leftscroll" href="#">>></a></div>
  <div id="buttonmove"> 
  <button type="button" id="button">Click Me!</button>
  <button type="button" id="button">Click Me!</button>
  <button type="button" id="button">Click Me!</button>
  <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
</div>
<div class="preyear">
  <a id="rightscroll" href="#"><<</a>
</div>   
</body>
</html>
```

When I execute this code this is not executed and show the error

Please help me out...

Answer (score 2):

Correct your brackets as shown below :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#leftscroll').click(function() {
      $('#buttonmove').animate({
        'marginLeft' : '+= 30px'
      });     //<----- here                  
   });     //<----- here               
});     //<----- here
```

Comment: @user3785854...i think above answer will solve your issue if need more help then comment.